# Expanded Windows View

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to make a window that can switch between expanded and compact view with by just clicking a button.

What I'm wondering is: Is there an easier way to resize and move all the controls on the form without manually setting their position and size?

It would certainly be easier if I could make two forms, a expanded and compact form, and then just switch between the two forms. But I couldn't figure out how to make them reference the same code.

Comment: move all the logic into separate class - and reuse it

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at fluid widths, and creating properties for Expanded/Compact mode? I've attached a simple example of how to have parts of your view bound to the "mode" of the window.

This technique lends itself to MVVM too. I've done a "weird" hybrid, instead of implementing a `DependencyProperty` for the bind-able properties, I've bound to the MainWindow and used that as the `ViewModel`. You can choose how you want to implement your binding.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:wpfApplication2="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=wpfApplication2:MainWindow, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Background="LightGray">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Really Long Text Example" Visibility="{Binding ExpandedVisibility}" />
                <TextBlock Text="Compact Text"  Visibility="{Binding CompactVisibility}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Really Long Text Example" Visibility="{Binding ExpandedVisibility}" />
                <TextBlock Text="Compact Text"  Visibility="{Binding CompactVisibility}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Really Long Text Example" Visibility="{Binding ExpandedVisibility}" />
                <TextBlock Text="Compact Text"  Visibility="{Binding CompactVisibility}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Really Long Text Example" Visibility="{Binding ExpandedVisibility}" />
                <TextBlock Text="Compact Text"  Visibility="{Binding CompactVisibility}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Border VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="50" Visibility="{Binding ExpandedVisibility}">
                <TextBlock Text="Non Compact Section Only" Background="#FFFFF593"></TextBlock>
            </Border>
            <Button Content="Compact / Expand" Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="2" Width="150">
            <Rectangle Visibility="{Binding ExpandedVisibility}" Fill="Red" />
            <Rectangle Visibility="{Binding CompactVisibility}" Fill="Blue" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _isExpandedMode;
        private Visibility _compactVisibility;

        public bool IsExpandedMode
        {
            get { return _isExpandedMode; }
            set
            {
                _isExpandedMode = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                OnPropertyChanged("ExpandedVisibility");
                OnPropertyChanged("CompactVisibility");
            }
        }

        public Visibility ExpandedVisibility
        {
            get { return IsExpandedMode ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed; }
        }

        public Visibility CompactVisibility
        {
            get { return !IsExpandedMode ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed; }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.IsExpandedMode = true;
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IsExpandedMode = !IsExpandedMode;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I copied all the code into a new project, there were 6 (4 individual) errors. INotifyPropertyChanged, PropertyChangedEventHandler, CallerMemberName, and CallerMemberNameAttribute were unable to be found.

Comment: I explicitly left out the namespace, and usings because they are somewhat irrelevant to the solution. The code was not intended to be a copy paste, solution. It was to suggest an approach. I have however, updated the code behind to include the usings and namespace, which should make it compile. This is written using `.NET4.5` also

Comment: So what about a form that has lots of buttons that would need to change size when the form is resized? How would you do that?

Comment: There are a few different approaches you could take. If the sizes of the controls are a factor of the original you could have a scaling property and multiply the width and height by the scale. Alternatively have your smaller controls in a "panel" that shows and hides like done in my example. So for one button, you'd have a full and compact version, both then link to the same functionality in the ViewModel. There's no holy grail solution to this, but you can make it easier for yourself.